# issue with the complete namespace appending when renamed the node

Tags: xslt-2.0

I renamed the A:B node to C:D but in the output, I am viewing the
the complete namespace of C which I don't require

I tried using
exclude-result-prefixes but it is not working

```
<xsl:stylesheet Xmlns:A="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/well-formed-delta-v1"
Xmlnx:C="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/non-namespaced-attribute">

<xsl:template match="node()[name()='A:B']" mode="fetchData">
    <xsl:element name="C:D" exclude-result-prefixes="merge">

        <xsl:attribute name="content">
            <xsl:variable name="A:B">
                <xsl:value-of select="A:B" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$A:B" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML changed from

```
<A:B xmlns:C="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/non-namespaced-attribute"
    content="Base>base</A:B>
                                                               <A:B xmlns:C="
    http: / www.deltaxml.com / ns / non-namespaced-attribute "
    content="Base1>base1</A:B>
                                                               <A:B xmlns:C="
    http: / www.deltaxml.com / ns / non-namespaced-attribute "
    content="Base2>base2</A:B>
```

to the following XML

```
<C:D xmlns:C="
    http: / www.deltaxml.com / ns / non-namespaced-attribute "
    content="Base>base</C:D>
                                                               <C:D xmlns:C="
    http: / www.deltaxml.com / ns / non-namespaced-attribute "
    content="Base1>base1</C:D>
                                                               <C:D xmlns:C="
    http: / www.deltaxml.com / ns / non-namespaced-attribute " content="Base2>
    base2
</C:D>
But I don't need the name space of C, Please suggest a solution
```

Comment: @Pritesh Please make useful and worthwile edits!